# fetch api catches exception occurring during react component rendering

Tags: redux, fetch-api

I have an action creator like this:

```
export function createTransaction (customerId) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(`/api/customers/${customerId}/transactions`, {
      method: 'post'
    })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(receiveNewTransaction())
      })
      .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err)
        alert('Something went wrong while creating transaction', err)
      })
  }
}
```

The value dispatched results in re-rendering of the component tree.
Inside render method of one of the components, somewhere deep in the tree, there is a function like this:

```
transactions.map(item => item)
```

Strangely, "transactions" above is not an array due to which an exception occurs, which is completely okay. What is not okay (imo) is the excection begin caught by the action creator!! Is it normal??

So, when the api call finishes, i see an error message in the browser console followed by the alert. This is the error message:

```
TypeError: transactions.map is not a function
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be caught in the action creator? The action creator causes a dispatch which causes a rerender which causes an exception. The top-level in the hierarchy is the action creator, which in this case has a `catch` block for a promise.

Comment: @Li357 I understand what you mean. I did not know this. I thought once the action is dispatched the job of the promises is done. Do you think catch here makes sense? The intention of catch here was to catch api errors only (I know fetch api resolves all https status codes as success and I have enhanced fetch api to throw error when http code > 400)